# Cannot add YAML to Intellij with gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml

I want to import configuration from `YAML` file that saved in `git`. I am using `Intellij` with `Gradle`. I read many documentation regarding this I did use installing all YAML plugins from `preferences` -> `plugins` like `SnakeYAML`, `FormatYaml`. The problem that when I am trying to create `YAML` object using :

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
```

I got this error from `Intellij`

```
 Cannot resolve symbol Yaml
```

I did check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318114/how-to-load-yml-propery-to-gradle) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521788/snakeyaml-by-example) but still have same issue.

I am asking if I have to add some changes to my

> build.gradle

or is there other plugins that I have to install?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Yaml in your Java code you need to add the compile dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.23'
}
```

Proof of work:

[image: Yaml dependency]

Answer (score 0):

Small update to **CrazyCoder** answer. To those that may have same issue; the above dependencies that provided by **CrazyCoder** not work fine for me, I found this

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.8.4'
}
```

taken [this](http://from%20https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/11/handling-yaml-format-rest-spring-boot/)